# Cluster mode in nodejs using PM2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, pm2

We are planning to use kubernetes to deploy node application in a AWS clustered environment. Just needed some advice about if its good practice to use nodejs clustered module for a distributed deployment in AWS. Or single process for single container is good in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not about "good" or "bad".
Using PM2 would mean you'd ask Kubernetes for multiple CPUs for your pod.
Not using PM2 would means you'd ask Kubernetes for one (or less) CPU for your pod, which would be easier for Kubernetes to schedule (possibly on multiple nodes).
Having one fat pod on one node is less reliable than having multiple smaller pods distributed across multiple nodes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I agree that is my thought process too. But is there any reference where its been shown PM2 has faced production maintenance problems in a clustered AWS environment.. I couldn't find much info. I am not in favour of any resource configuration in the code

Comment: I didn't say or imply that PM2 faced a maintenance problem. I said the pod would request more resources and will be more difficult for Kubernetes to schedule. Instead of reading my answer you're coming up with your own conclusions, which makes me wonder why you bother asking here?

Comment: Pls refrain improper language..Difficulty in scheduling is a maintenance problem and that's what I meant.. Below is the kind of reference I am referring too.. May be this helps you as well.. https://www.linux.com/blog/pitfalls-avoid-when-implementing-nodejs-and-containers